# When can we leave out ли?

Tags: грамматика

In what cases can we leave out "ли"?

Я не знаю умер он или нет

**or**

Я не знаю умер ли он.

Basically when should I use ли?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We use "ли" mostly in yes/no questions

> Любите ли вы театр?

You can leave out *ли*

> Вы любите театр?

Mind the word order.We use inversion in the first sentence. 
We also use "ли" in reported yes/no questions like in those examples of yours.

> Я не знаю, придет ли он сегодня.

Ли functions as *if* or *whether*. We can't leave out *ли* or change the word order,but we can use another sentence with almost the same meaning with *или*.

> Я не знаю, придет он или нет сегодня.

Нет adds the emphasis to the sentence.

Comment: Do I need special intonation if I don't use ли? (In the last one).

Comment: Whether you want to add intonation or not is a choice of your own.

Comment: Stress the verb придет and emphatic нет equally. A rising intonation is used sometimes to express doubt, but neutral is also common, like in a usual affirmative sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, "ли" can be treated as "whether"/"if". When you want to ask some indirect question. For instance:

*I don't know whether he has done his homework or not.*

*Я не знаю сделал **ли** он свою домашнюю работу или нет.*

Comment: I think **ли** (or **или нет**) is redundant in your Russian version; _ли_ and _или_ usually don't combine well in simple sentences like this one.

Comment: Not sure from the strict grammar point of view about this redundancy, but basically it does work in everyday speech.

Comment: Yes, one can hear smth. like that here and there, but unlikely it's a good learning example, unless you say that **ли** _must_ be omitted in it (considering the question asked). Here's http://www.learnrussianweb.com/2010/05/1_4737.html a direct reminder to a learner: **В предложениях с "или" нам не нужно "ли"! We don´t need ли in или-sentences!**  (with examples)